# production app crashes while loading after upgrade to expo 49

Tags: react-native, expo

1. SDK Version: 49
2. Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): ios

After upgrading to expo SDK 49, the production app crashes as soon as it starts, before loading any assets (no Sentry captureMessage or error emitted). The development version works well on the simulator. The production version works well with SDK 48.

Any idea about what might be happening? I have been trying to fix this for some time and running out of ideas. Thanks so much for any help!

Here is the crash report from XCode and packge.json below:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process: StarboardSail [19274]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18e37e5e0 __exceptionPreprocess + 164 (NSException.m:249)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1866b3c00 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:356)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x18e403248 -[NSException raise] + 16 (NSException.m:129)
3   StarboardSail                   0x100dfb210 0x100d88000 + 471568
4   StarboardSail                   0x100e2faec 0x100d88000 + 686828
5   StarboardSail                   0x100ef4294 0x100d88000 + 1491604
6   StarboardSail                   0x100ef4554 0x100d88000 + 1492308
7   StarboardSail                   0x100eb2678 0x100d88000 + 1222264
8   StarboardSail                   0x100e9e574 0x100d88000 + 1140084
9   StarboardSail                   0x1010d7898 0x100d88000 + 3471512
10  StarboardSail                   0x100e9e4b0 0x100d88000 + 1139888
11  StarboardSail                   0x100d8c3f0 0x100d88000 + 17392
12  UIKitCore                       0x1906b8184 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 320 (UIApplication.m:2402)
13  UIKitCore                       0x1906b72ec -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:] + 2856 (UIApplication.m:2840)
14  UIKitCore                       0x1906b62d0 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 856 (UIApplication.m:4684)
15  UIKitCore                       0x1906b5f1c -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 132 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:450)
16  UIKitCore                       0x190632988 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 112 (_UISceneLifecycleState.m:109)
17  UIKitCore                       0x1906b9eac __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 216 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:566)
18  UIKitCore                       0x1905ded7c -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 220 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:515)
19  UIKitCore                       0x1905dd7f4 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 608 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:565)
20  UIKitCore                       0x1905dd15c -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 248 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:468)
21  UIKitCore                       0x1905dd02c __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block... + 148 (_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction.m:73)
22  UIKitCore                       0x1905dcf34 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:fromCurrentState:actions:completion:] + 736 (BSAnimationSettings+UIKit.m:54)
23  UIKitCore                       0x1905dc7bc _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContextAndCompletion + 224 (_UISceneSettingsDiffAction.m:27)
24  UIKitCore                       0x1905dc46c -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 316 (_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction.m:58)
25  UIKitCore                       0x19095b87c __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.225 + 612 (UIScene.m:2069)
26  UIKitCore                       0x1905db5f0 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 216 (UIScene.m:1723)
27  UIKitCore                       0x1905db460 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 244 (UIScene.m:2028)
28  UIKitCore                       0x1906f63d4 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 508 (UIApplication.m:4129)
29  UIKitCore                       0x1906f616c -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 288 (UIApplicationSceneClientAgent.m:47)
30  FrontBoardServices              0x1a63a5aa8 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 324 (FBSScene.m:545)
31  FrontBoardServices              0x1a63a5944 __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.108 + 280 (FBSWorkspaceScenesClient.m:480)
32  FrontBoardServices              0x1a63a45a8 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 168 (FBSWorkspace.m:411)
33  FrontBoardServices              0x1a63b0360 __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 352 (FBSWorkspaceScenesClient.m:468)
34  libdispatch.dylib               0x1961bf300 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:561)
35  libdispatch.dylib               0x1961c2d48 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 284 (queue.c:496)
36  FrontBoardServices              0x1a63a09ec __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 52 (FBSSerialQueue.m:285)
37  FrontBoardServices              0x1a63a096c -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 240 (FBSSerialQueue.m:309)
38  FrontBoardServices              0x1a63a0844 -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28 (FBSSerialQueue.m:322)
39  CoreFoundation                  0x18e2c8acc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28 (CFRunLoop.c:1957)
40  CoreFoundation                  0x18e2c7d48 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176 (CFRunLoop.c:2001)
41  CoreFoundation                  0x18e2c655c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 340 (CFRunLoop.c:2046)
42  CoreFoundation                  0x18e2c5238 __CFRunLoopRun + 828 (CFRunLoop.c:2955)
43  CoreFoundation                  0x18e2c4e18 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608 (CFRunLoop.c:3420)
44  GraphicsServices                0x1d0d895ec GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2196)
45  UIKitCore                       0x1906d32fc -[UIApplication _run] + 888 (UIApplication.m:3690)
46  UIKitCore                       0x1906d2938 UIApplicationMain + 340 (UIApplication.m:5275)
47  StarboardSail                   0x100d8c764 0x100d88000 + 18276
48  dyld                            0x1b0aafd44 start + 2104 (dyldMain.cpp:1269)
```

package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "lint": "eslint *.js **/*.js",
    "images": "node scripts/images.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "~7.2.2",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.16",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@sentry/react-native": "5.5.0",
    "algoliasearch": "^4.20.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "core-js": "^3.10.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
    "dayjs-plugin-utc": "^0.1.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "expo": "^49.0.13",
    "expo-application": "~5.3.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.10.1",
    "expo-blur": "~12.4.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.8.3",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-contacts": "~12.2.0",
    "expo-crypto": "~12.4.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.11",
    "expo-device": "~5.4.0",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-linking": "~5.0.2",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.20.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-secure-store": "~12.3.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-task-manager": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.18.16",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.3.2",
    "firebase": "^9.23.0",
    "formik": "^2.4.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-devtools-core": "^4.23.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-instantsearch-native": "^6.38.1",
    "react-native": "0.72.5",
    "react-native-base64": "0.0.2",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.5.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "2.4.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-localize": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-maps": "1.7.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-native-webview": "13.2.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.2.3",
    "sentry-expo": "~7.0.0",
    "uuid": "^7.0.3",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "metro": "^0.76.8",
    "metro-config": "^0.76.8",
    "metro-core": "^0.76.8",
    "react-native-flipper": "^0.163.0",
    "redux-flipper": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```